# Why aren't we getting the same instance of the CustomerViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

We're using MVVM Light. We have to make multiple instances of the same small collection of classes: CustomerViewModel, ProductViewModel and OrdersViewModel. In an effort to make sure that we're invoking the same instance of any of those classes we create a GUID and associated it with each instance of any of those 3 classes. This is our first time using MVVM Light. Its our understanding that MVVM Light will use the Singleton pattern each time you invoke calls like GetInstance specifying a particular instance. So in order to assure that we're calling the same one we pass in the GUID we associated with a particular class earlier. And yet it is failing all of the time.

We've been trashing away at this for 3 weeks and are no closer to getting it solved.

I've set breakpoints in the constructor of the Customer class to see what the GUID is:

```
public CustomerViewModel()
{
   RefreshList();
   AvailableFields = typeof(Customer).GetProperties().Select(a => a.Name).ToList<String>();
}
```

I'll set a breakpoint on RefreshList(). (Our RefreshList() method is used to fetch data which is then displayed in a data grid in the view.) As you can see the class's name is CustomerViewModel.

But then later when we're trying to navigate to the customer detail viewmodel, it invokes what should be the same instance of CustomerViewModel in this case:

```
public static CustomerViewModel GetCustomersById(string id)
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CustomerViewModel>(id);
}
```

This code is in the ViewModelLocator. I've set a breakpoint on the return statement and checked the value of id, which should be equal to the GUID previously create. It never is. Why not? What are we doing wrong?

Comment: _I've set a breakpoint on the return statement and checked the value of id, which should be equal to the GUID previously create. It never is._  Are you saying the value of `id` passed into `GetCustomersById` is not what you'd expect it to be?

Comment: Yes Patrick, that's exactly correct. We generate a GUID and store it into the CustomerViewModel as a string property. After the CustomerViewModel is created in the constructor I've checked it to see what it is. Then later when the GetCustomersById is called, it is passed the wrong GUID and the constructor gets called again, so now we have a new instance, etc.

Comment: @Rod can you add some more details on how you add and setup the SimpleIOC with this CustomerViewModel? We only see the GetInstance call now...